# Finding Number Of Compares in this specific Quick-sort Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have an algorithm for Quick-Sort and I want to return the number of compares in it but I can not make anything of the given algorithm. I have to return the compares form getCompares() function. I have checked at many places online but I have not found any proper solution to this. The no. of compares for 
 already sorted data for the size of 100 should give 488 as the result.

```
/**
 * Quicksort algorithm.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 */

public static void QuickSort( Comparable [ ] a )

{
    quicksort( a, 0, a.length - 1 );
}

private static final int CUTOFF = 10;

/**
 * Method to swap to elements in an array.
 * @param a an array of objects.
 * @param index1 the index of the first object.
 * @param index2 the index of the second object.
 */
public static final void swapReferences( Object [ ] a, int index1, int index2 )
{
    Object tmp = a[ index1 ];
    a[ index1 ] = a[ index2 ];
    a[ index2 ] = tmp;
}

/**
 * Internal quicksort method that makes recursive calls.
 * Uses median-of-three partitioning and a cutoff of 10.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 * @param low the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param high the right-most index of the subarray.
 */
private static void quicksort( Comparable [ ] a, int low, int high )
{
    if( low + CUTOFF > high )
        insertionSort( a, low, high );
    else
    {
            // Sort low, middle, high
        int middle = ( low + high ) / 2;
        if( a[ middle ].compareTo( a[ low ] ) < 0 )
            swapReferences( a, low, middle );
        if( a[ high ].compareTo( a[ low ] ) < 0 )
            swapReferences( a, low, high );
        if( a[ high ].compareTo( a[ middle ] ) < 0 )
            swapReferences( a, middle, high );

            // Place pivot at position high - 1
        swapReferences( a, middle, high - 1 );
        Comparable pivot = a[ high - 1 ];

            // Begin partitioning
        int i, j;
        for( i = low, j = high - 1; ; )
        {
            while( a[ ++i ].compareTo( pivot ) < 0 )
                ;
            while( pivot.compareTo( a[ --j ] ) < 0 )
                ;
            if( i >= j )
                break;
            swapReferences( a, i, j );
        }

            // Restore pivot
        swapReferences( a, i, high - 1 );

        quicksort( a, low, i - 1 );    // Sort small elements
        quicksort( a, i + 1, high );   // Sort large elements
    }
}

/**
 * Internal insertion sort routine for subarrays
 * that is used by quicksort.
 * @param a an array of Comparable items.
 * @param low the left-most index of the subarray.
 * @param n the number of items to sort.
 */
private static void insertionSort( Comparable [ ] a, int low, int high )
{
    for( int p = low + 1; p <= high; p++ )
    {
        Comparable tmp = a[ p ];
        int j;

        for( j = p; j > low && tmp.compareTo( a[ j - 1 ] ) < 0; j-- )
            a[ j ] = a[ j - 1 ];
        a[ j ] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: just for confirmation of my understanding, you want total no. of compares as output produced by the program for testcase that is given to you.

Comment: for already sorted data, no. of compares would be much greater than 488 for size 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to create an internal method for comparing 2 `Comparable` objects that counts the number of times it is invoked and replace all the `compareTo` calls with a call to that method.

```
private int comparisons = 0;

private int compare(Comparable<?> obj1, Comparable<?> obj2) {
    comparisons++;
    return obj1.compareTo(obj2);
}
```

Then replace expressions like `tmp.compareTo(a[j-1])` with `compare(tmp, a[j-1])`.

Your `getCompares` method would return `comparisons`.

A couple of other tips to consider:

Ideally don't use static methods and variables. Make a `QuickSort` class that needs to be instantiated before use.

Best not to use raw types (such as `Comparable` in your code). Most modern IDEs correctly warn about the dangers of this. Either use a wildcard (as above) or, better, actually add a generic type to your `QuickSort` class:

```
class QuickSort<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    public void sort(T[] array) { ... }
}

QuickSort<Integer> intSorter = new QuickSort<>();
int[] array = {5, 8, 2};
intSorter.sort(array);
```

This will allow compile time checks that you aren't mixing incompatible types. Your current raw types won't allow Java to do that.

Comment: Alright, I got the results I was looking for. Thanks. The algorithm that my professor gave is kinda old so that's why it has the static methods and raw data types but thanks for the tip!